# Angular: Reload $rootscope user before initializing controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-rootscope, angular-controller

I'm working on a SPA with AngularJS. After the sign in, a cookie is created with a token and a user object is stored in `$rootScope.user` which is conveniently accessible from various controllers as they are dynamically loaded.

The application works fine when I use it normally and navigate around.

When I refresh a page with F5, angular is reloaded and the module run() method checks if the cookie exists and reloads the user from the server into `$rootScope.user`. However, while this is happening, another controller is already expecting `$rootScope.user` to have a user.

How can I prevent controller initialization before my `$rootScope.user` is ready and loaded. If can, of course, check in the controller if there is a user loaded in `$rootScope`. But if there isn't, how can `$rootScope` invoke a controller to carry out some initialization?

Here is code in app.run():

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $cookies, appServices) {

    var token = $cookies.get('UserToken');
    if (token) $rootScope.token = token;

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

        // Get user from server if token is there but no user
        if ($rootScope.user == null) {
            if ($rootScope.token) {
                appServices.getUserByToken(token).then(function (d) {
                    if (d.Code == 1) {
                        $rootScope.user = d.ReturnObj;
                        if ($rootScope.user != null && next.templateUrl == "web/views/signin.html") $location.path("/dashboard");
                    } else $rootScope.goSignin(next.templateUrl);
                });
            }
            else $rootScope.goSignin(next.templateUrl);
        }
    });
})
```

And here is sample code in a controller that is dynamically loaded:

```
app.registerCtrl('userdetailCtrl', function userdetailCtrl($scope, $http, $rootScope, $routeParams, appServices, $location, validationService) {

  $scope.getOffices=function()
    {
      appServices.getOffices({ ID: $rootScope.user.OrgID, Token: $rootScope.token }).then(function (d){
      if(d.Code==1){$scope.office = d.ReturnObj;}});
    }

  $scope.getOffices();

});
```

The `getOffices()` function requires `$rootScope.user.OrgID`, which is not found as `$rootScope.user` is not yet loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: put a `watch` on it?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how I would do this? Am a bit new with Angular.

Comment: sure, i added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work in your situation, but

```
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
    //fetch user here
}
```

solved a similar issue that I had

Comment: I'm not using ng-include. Views and controllers are loaded via ng-view and routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things, here's an example of two of these. Check the console in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5oeLnt0b/4/)

#### 1. Watch the variable for changes:

The first is watching `$rootScope.user` for changes in your controller:

App.run:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.user = 'user';
}, 500)
```

in your controller:

```
$rootScope.$watch('user', function(newVal, oldVal) {
   console.log(newVal, $rootScope.user); 
});
```

You can 'unwatch', too, if you don't want to keep executing code every time the user variable changes.

#### 2. Emitting an event

The second is emitting an event, and catching it where required, like this:

App.run:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.user = 'user';
    $rootScope.$broadcast('userEvent');
}, 500)
```

Your controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('userEvent', function() {
    console.log($rootScope.user);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good solution. But I don't want to implement a $watch or $broadcast simply for the rare chance of a browser page refresh. This would mean I would need to write mostly unnecessary code to check for `$rootScope` in many controllers. What I was looking for is a way to halt controller initialization until certain conditions were met.

Comment: Your design might need tweaking then. Maybe a user service instead of a rootscope variable, and chain the promises?

Comment: Using $timeout to 'resolve' any async issues is really never a good idea. All these should be addressed with "promises" and "resolve". Create a user service (like @jorge said) that returns a promise... Then put the user service in the route.resolve. Then it will wait for the user to resolve. I would advise reading up on "promise", "resolve", "route resolve". These are essential and should be mastered when dealing with async operations.

Comment: "write mostly unnecessary code to check" - Uhm? Writing checks is never unnecessary. I think 20% of "our" work consists of doing cool stuff... The other time is spend on writing code to make sure it works in all situations...